# Use conditions in Ansible task vars

Tags: ansible

```
- roles
  - consul
    - vars/main.yml
```

In `main.yml` I try:

```
consul_is_server: {{ true if consul_server is defined else false }}
```

And playbook:

```
- hosts: consul-server
  roles:
    - consul
  vars:
    consul_server: true
```

Got error:

```
consul_is_server: {{ "true" if consul_server is defined else "false" }}
                            ^
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes.  Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value. For instance:

    with_items:
      - {{ foo }}

Should be written as:

    with_items:
      - "{{ foo }}"
```

How can I use conditions in task vars?

Comment: variables cannot contain spaces...http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#what-makes-a-valid-variable-name

Comment: Could you try enclosing it within double quotes like `consul_is_server: "{{ 'true' if consul_server is defined else 'false' }}"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now made it works:

```
consul_is_server:  >
    {{ true  if consul_server is defined and consul_server==true else false }}
```

But in this case `consul_is_server` is string: "False" or "True".

So, when use this var in templates I need to use cast to `bool`:

```
"server": {{ "true" if consul_is_server |bool else "false" }}
```

Answer (score 2):

Vars files are not meant to contain conditionals, They should contain only variables. Conditionals are used in the tasks sections of a playbook.

```
vars:
  consul_server: true
```

Then a conditional execution might look like:

```
tasks:
  - shell: echo "This certainly is consul_server!"
    when: consul_server
```

Comment: In this case I should add `vars:
  consul_server: true` in all playbooks. I don't need it.

Comment: And no, vars can contain conditionals.